# Image array incomplete in vue.js template

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have an array of images which are stored as  element strings. I use this template code in vue 3 (Quasar framework) to display the pictures:

```
<template>
  <div class="bg-white shadow-2"
    style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); height: 750px; width: 820px;">
    <FullCalendar :options="options"
      style="position: absolute; top: 40%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); height: 600px; width: 700px;">
    </FullCalendar>
    <div class="q-pa-md"
      style="position: absolute; top: 86%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); height: 100px; width: 800px;">
      <q-carousel v-model="slide" transition-prev="slide-right" transition-next="slide-left" swipeable animated
        control-color="amber" navigation padding arrows height="130px" class="bg-white shadow-2">
          <q-carousel-slide :name="1" class="column no-wrap">
            <div class="image-container">
              <q-img v-for="image in images" :key="image" :name="image" :src="image" class="rounded-borders"
                style="width: 54px;" />
            </div>
          </q-carousel-slide>
      </q-carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
.image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(60px, 1fr));
  gap: 10px;
  margin-left: 180px;
}
</style>
```

However, only two of the array's images are being shown, the first and the last element of the array! All images in between are somehow left out! Here is a screenshot from what is being displayed:
[image]

Since I retrieve the images from database, I tried the array to the console to check if it is populated correctly and completely as well as changing the image data multiple times to ensure that the images are not being converted to  strings incorrectly...
All in vain, of course!

Comment: without looking into `images` array code, It will be difficult to say anything about this issue.

Comment: Hi, here is the array: const images = ref<string[]>([])   images.value = [
  'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...',
  'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...',
  'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...'
  'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...']  The full paths are too long so I replaced the rest with '...'

Comment: Your `images` array looks good only. It should work. Can you just print `{{ images }}` in the template to see what you are getting. I think debugging will only work to help.

Comment: Thenks for replying! The problem was that all of the image urls except those of the first and last element of the arrays were accidentally invalid!